# How do I kill a process whose PID is in a PID file?

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `pidfile`, that stores the PID of a process.

How can I kill the pid in `pidfile` programmatically using Ruby, assuming I just know the filename, and not the actual PID in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Process.kill(15, File.read('pidfile').to_i)
```

or even

```
Process.kill 15, File.read('pidfile').to_i
```

Now, you could also do something like:

```
system "kill `cat pidfile`" # or `kill \`cat pidfile\``
```

However, that approach has more overhead, is vulnerable to code injection exploits, is less portable, and is generally just more of a shell script wrapped in Ruby as opposed to actual Ruby code.